# Pre/Post-build event command-line dialog box

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I'm building a Visual Studio extension and would like to use the same pre/post-build dialog box that's used in the C# and VB language systems:

[image: pre/post-build command-line editor]

Is that control available to extension developers?  I've looked through the VSSDK and can't find it. If it is available, how can it be accessed?

Comment: Do you mean create a custom tool window like pre/post-build dialog box or build vsx project by using pre/post-build dialog?

Comment: I meant the latter -- build a vsx project using the pre/post-build dialog. I ended up writing a custom dialog with the same appearance and behavior. It took several hours, and I'd still be interested to know whether I could have used the one that comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: If you want to create a custom tool windows, please refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138567.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396